# How Can I insert to column B if Column A have an specific valor?

Tags: sql

I need to insert in column PriceA a value if Column Price have an specific Value, for example

create table Item2 (
  Price int, 
  PriceA int 
  )

Insert into Item2 (price, PriceA)
   values 
   (99,0), (56,0),(69,3),(89,0),(99,0),(99,0)

Insert into Item2 (Price,PriceA)
Select
  Case
    When item2.Price = '99'
    Then item2.PriceA = '120'
    Else ''
  End
  from Item2

Answer (score 0):

```
 Insert into Item2 values (Price,PriceA) 
 SELECT Price, CASE WHEN Price = '99' THEN '120'
                    ELSE ''
               END as PriceA
 FROM YourTable
```

The other option is with one `insert trigger` on table Item2